# Inspect the history stack of the current chrome tab?

Tags: google-chrome

I am building a page in my application that contains an iframe. The behavior of the back and forward buttons keep surprising me.

Therefor I wonder if there is any way to inspect the history stack of the  current chrome tab?

Answer (score 1):

The back and forward buttons do not take into account any JavaScript
[AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) calls.
Your JavaScript application may hijack the Back and Forward buttons
and do its own stuff, and you can find JavaScript libraries for doing that.

Apart from that, the best way under Chrome to track the working of your page,
is to use the [Chrome DevTools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/).
These tools can do
[Network Analysis Reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/reference).
By default, DevTools records all network requests in the Network panel, so long as DevTools is open:

[image]

Comment: ok so.... how do inspect the history stack using chrome devtools?